# Facebook Application Post To Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

Can anyone explain how to make an application, that updates users status, let's say every 10 mins, once he authorizes the access using the latest FB SDK.

Comment: Have you read facebook documentation?

Comment: EVERY 10 minutes!!!! Your app will get flagged as a spam and get blocked before you know it!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the proper method for posting to a user here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#posts

Once you have your application working you should be able to use something like CRON to enable it to run and update the user status at various intervals.

As mentioned in one of the comments every 10 minutes seems excessive so be sure you're abiding by Facebook's terms of service with whatever your doing.  Most of the time as long as the action your going to be taking is explained clearly to the user as they're authorizing your application you should be alright.